# Where clause on dynamic column name in LINQ query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, where-clause

I've created a dropdown with some column names in a table in my db. When a user selects a column name i want to add a where clause to the query to use this filter.

What i'm trying to do is:

```
Dim objQuery = (From wc In _dbBellen.dealer_telefonies Order By wc.Bedrijfsnaam Select wc)

'if dropdown has value...

objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) wc.DynamicColumnName < txtFilterValue1.Text)
```

The wc.DynamicColumnName has to be replaced by for example wc.Price.

--

The code what i'm tried now after some replies is:

```
    Dim objQuery = (From wc In _dbBellen.dealer_telefonies Order By wc.Bedrijfsnaam Select wc)

        If ddlFilterColumn1.SelectedValue <> "" And ddlFilterOperator1.SelectedValue <> "" And txtFilterValue1.Text <> "" Then

            Select Case ddlFilterOperator1.SelectedValue
                Case "..%"
                    objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) wc.WHMCSClient_id Like txtFilterValue1.Text & "%")
                Case "%.."
                    objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) wc.WHMCSClient_id Like "%" & txtFilterValue1.Text)
                Case Else '< > = <>
                    'objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) wc.WHMCSClient_id < txtFilterValue1.Text)
                    'objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) "wc." + ddlFilterColumn1.SelectedValue.ToString + " < " + txtFilterValue1.Text)
                    objQuery = objQuery.Where(Function(wc) "wc.WHMCSClient_id < 500")
            End Select

        End If

    Response.Write(objQuery.ToString())
```

But i am getting the following error (original error is in dutch but it said as follow): 
The conversion from string wc.WHMCSClient_id < 500 to type Boolean is invalid.

Comment: Hopefully someone can give you a better example, but you probably want [How to use expression trees to build dynamic queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is quite an old article, but I think it's still viable*

Scott Gu posted about the Dynamic LINQ library a while back which essentially allows you to use strings to query collections in a "LINQ"-type format., i.e. something like this:

```
Dim objQuery = (From wc In _dbBellen.dealer_telefonies Order By wc.Bedrijfsnaam Select wc)

// if dropdown has value...
Dim result = objQuery.Where("MyColumnName < " + txtFilterValue1.Text);
```

Here's a link to the full article: [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: I've tried but i will get a warning that it can't be casted right when running, please see original message above for my new code.

Comment: You don't need to use the `Function(wc)` declaration, it's simply a `string` passed into the dynamic LINQ `.Where` clause.

Comment: When i only pass a string, my Visual Studio warns me directly that this function does not take that many arguments. The example in the link is C# is guess, i'm working in VB.

Comment: The example is both C# and VB. Visual Studio won't recognise it until you include the dynamic LINQ library and include the namespace at the top. Half way through the article is a link to a basic VB demo. http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqvb.zip

Comment: Ahhh, nice! I thought it should work with the native library. Got it working now, happy me!